# How to control keyboard's backlight using python on windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, keyboard, backlight

I want to control my laptop's backlight keyboard using python. My platform is windows. I can't find any way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can control this using the [dbus library](https://pypi.org/project/dbus-python/), using the following code [from this wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_backlight):

```
import dbus
import sys

def kb_light_set(delta):
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    kbd_backlight_proxy = bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.UPower', '/org/freedesktop/UPower/KbdBacklight')
    kbd_backlight = dbus.Interface(kbd_backlight_proxy, 'org.freedesktop.UPower.KbdBacklight')

    current = kbd_backlight.GetBrightness()
    maximum = kbd_backlight.GetMaxBrightness()
    new = max(0, min(current + delta, maximum))

    if 0 <= new <= maximum:
        current = new
        kbd_backlight.SetBrightness(current)

    # Return current backlight level percentage
    return 100 * current / maximum

if __name__ ==  '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2 or len(sys.argv) == 3:
        if sys.argv[1] == "--up" or sys.argv[1] == "+":
            if len(sys.argv) == 3:
                print(kb_light_set(int(sys.argv[2])))
            else:
                print(kb_light_set(17))
        elif sys.argv[1] == "--down" or sys.argv[1] == "-":
            if len(sys.argv) == 3:
                print(kb_light_set(-int(sys.argv[2])))
            else:
                print(kb_light_set(-17))
        else:
            print("Unknown argument:", sys.argv[1])
    else:
        print("Script takes one or two argument.", len(sys.argv) - 1, "arguments provided.")
```

> **The following is an example implementation in Python 3. Install upower and python-dbus packages then place the following script in `/usr/local/bin/` and make it executable. You can then map your keyboard shortcuts to run `/usr/local/bin/kb-light.py + x` and `/usr/local/bin/kb-light.py - x` to increase and decrease your keyboard backlight level by x amounts.**

Comment: I am using **WINDOWS**  platform. I want a solution for windows platform not for linux.