# How can I change keyboard backlight timeout on XPG Xenia 16 RX gaming laptop?

Tags: windows, keyboard, timeout, hardware, led

I am quite desperate with my problem, so any ideas would be really appreciated.

I bought one of ADATA XPG's gaming laptops, Xenia 16 RX, back in November 2023. It has keyboard LEDs which can be customized either manually (using hotkeys from the keyboard) or from the official app. Unfortunately, the app fails to install, and there is no way to manually set keyboard backlight timeout. Right now my keyboard backlight turns off every 60 seconds if I do not use the keyboard. I need to press any key to trigger the backlight.

## Trying to install the official app

There seems to be a problem with an official app for keyboard and fans control. It is called **Gaming Center** and may be downloaded from the [official XPG website](https://www.xpg.com/ru/xpg/pc-system-xenia16-rx-gaming-notebook?tab=download) after specifying the vendor code (there's only one option there) and the OS (Windows 10).

The installation is interrupted by an error message:

> L507 Provision app package fail. Result: 0x80073CF1

Some of the customers reported the same problem, but ADATA doesn't seem to care about it, and there is no way to ask for a feedback unless I use my warranty (which is a long and complicated process). Some people managed to install the app, but no-one knows what causes the problem.

Here's what I've tried:

- installing Windows 10, installing GPU and chipset drivers from XPG website
- reinstalling Windows 10, installing GPU and chipset drivers from AMD website
- updating to Windows 11 and doing the same

Nothing worked, the error occurs every time I try ro install the app.

Except for the cases described above, I installed all the drivers and utilities from XPG website.

## Trying to find another way to change backlight timeout

I can only change the regime and the brightness using a combination of <kbd>Fn</kbd> and arrow keys.

Here's what I've tried:

- entering BIOS and searching for an option that would allow me to change keyboard backlit timeout (as I've seen such option for some non-XPG laptops). There was none, and my laptop's BIOS seems to have very limited amount of options.
- trying to enter BIOS advanced regime using <kbd>F10</kbd> instead of <kbd>F2</kbd> (didn't work), pressing <kbd>A</kbd> right after entering BIOS (didn't work)
- trying [OpenRGB](https://openrgb.org/) instead of my laptop's native app, but it failed to identify my keyboard
- trying to find the appropriate parameter somewhere in Windows settings menu or in Windows registry (didn't find anything)

My last try was to create some kind of a script that would emulate key pressing every 50-60 seconds. I installed [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) and tried this:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, PressTheKey, 60000
Return
PressTheKey:
Send, {NumLock}
Return
```

While it does work (<kbd>NumLock</kbd> is enabled and disabled every minute), it fails to emulate the *physical* key pressing. [This AutoHotKey forum topic](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/80130-is-it-possible-to-simulate-physical-key-press/) states that this level of emulation is not possible via AutoHotKey.

I also tried Python script from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54624221/simulate-physical-keypress-in-python-without-raising-lowlevelkeyhookinjected-0), and the result was the same (it worked, but failed to trigger keyboard backlight).

At this point, I would love to hear any suggestions. I'm not an experienced Windows user, my main OS is Linux (Ubuntu).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check out this post: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61304198/how-to-control-keyboards-backlight-using-python-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the official app. The installer certificate expired on October 20, 2023. You need to set the system clock before this date.